# Binomial Distribution Approximation

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I would like to ask about this question:

For an upcoming election, reports suggest that 52 percent of voters favour candidate A. If 70 million voters will be voting soon, approximate the probability that A wins, assuming the candidate who receives more than half of the votes wins.

I tried to use normal approximation but the z value I got is -334 which is not very useful.

p=0.52

q=1-p=0.48

mean = np = (0.52)(70,000,000)=36,400,000

variance = npq = (0.52)(70,000,000)(0.48) = 17,472,000

std dev = 4179.952153

So Probability to win = 1 - P(x<=35,000,000)

Using normal approximation

P(x<= 35,000,000)= P(z <= (35,000,000-(36,400,000))/4179.952153)= P(z<=-334.9)

??? In the standard normal distribution, z values typically ranges from -3 to 3?

I am thinking could I use n = 70 and >35 success trials instead, by expressing them in millions?

Thanks!

Comment: "Reports suggest"--based on what?  It certainly wasn't a sample of 70 million people.

Comment: A wins if his number of votes is at least half, so your z score actually goes the other way--A is almost assured to win of you just need a Binomial (70 million,0.52) to be at least 35 million. (On the other hand this model has serious issues...)

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that X is the number (in millions), of voters who vote for Candidate A. This will give you P(X>35). Using continuity correction, this then becomes P(X>35.5). You should get P(Z> -0.22) after normal approximation. This is simply 0.5 + 0.08706(from the Z table) = 0.58706.

Comment: Thanks! I did this as this seems to be the only way.

Comment: That doesn't really make very much sense--why is a block of a million voters an independent Bernoulli trial counting for one "vote" somehow while each voter is not separate?